# Says "variable pg1 may not have not been initialized", but it clearly is and I do not see any possible outcomes where it can't be?

Tags: java, initialization, jgrasp

I am trying to write a choose your own adventure code outline for my class but it says that my variable pg1 has not been initialized but it clearly has and I do not see an outcome where it wouldn't be?  Can someone take a look for me and help trouble shoot it?

```
 public static boolean decOne()  //the first desicion to make
   {
      boolean nxt = false;
      boolean bonus = false;
      int pg1;
      Object[] options = {"opt1","opt2","opt3","opt4"};
      while(nxt == false)
            pg1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"story text goes here","title goes here",1,1,null,options,options[0]);
            if(pg1==0)
            {
               bonus = true;
               nxt = false;
            }
            else if(pg1==1)
            {
               nxt = false;
            }
            else if(pg1==2)
            {
               nxt = true;
            }
            else if(pg1==3)
            {
               nxt = false;
            }
            return bonus;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a brace after the `while` statement

Answer (score 0):

I actually just messed up my brackets oops.  Hopefully if u are having the same issue looking at your brackets fixes it!